# Eclipse, I can't launch a new project on the phone

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a problem. I make a new android aplication project, just simple hello world and try to run it on my phone ( 4.3 android ).

My app. is launching and suddenly it shut down and show message like "Application was stopped".

0 bugs, 0 errors i didn't change anything in code. 
Only in logcat something is wrong i think.

```
    10-29 21:58:07.226: W/dalvikvm(4954): Unable to resolve superclass ofLcom/example/psw2/MainActivity; (2)
10-29 21:58:07.226: W/dalvikvm(4954): Link of class 'Lcom/example/psw2/MainActivity;' failed
10-29 21:58:07.231: D/AndroidRuntime(4954): Shutting down VM
10-29 21:58:07.231: W/dalvikvm(4954): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f0b700)
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.psw2/com.example.psw2.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.psw2.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.psw2-1.apk
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2219)
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.psw2.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.psw2-1.apk
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
10-29 21:58:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: The logcat specifically mentions that it can't find the superclass of your `MainActivity`- what is the super class (the full name including package) of that Activity?

Comment: `package com.example.psw2;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity`    I don't know if I well understand you, is that what you want?

Comment: It sounds like the v7 support library isn't being properly included when Eclipse generates the APK. Double check your project settings to make sure you are including that library then try restarting Eclipse and doing a clean + build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I get it !

I had to tick in Order and Export all items and it run!

Thanks for help